# Layover time of 30 min for connecting Jet Airways flights

Tags: short-connections, bom, jet-airways

I will be travelling from Udaipur to Bangalore via connecting flights. My first flight will land in Mumbai at 8:15 AM and the second one will depart from Mumbai at 8:45 AM. Both are Jet Airways flights.

Actually these tickets have been provided to me by my employer. I shared my concern with them that the layover time is very short, and the chances of missing flights are high. But they are saying that Jet Airways will make sure that I make it to the second flight. But still I have my doubts.

Can you please tell me if this is a fine arrangement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this all on one ticket?

Comment: Jet Airways would put you on a different place if there is one. Is there another one to Udaipur on the same day?

Comment: I really would like to know how it worked out for you. Were you able to make it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It's important to know if it's one ticket from Udaipur to Bangalore, or a ticket from Udaipur to Mumbai and a second ticket from Mumbai to Bangalore. If it is one ticket, the airline is responsible for getting you to Bangalore and they will, in theory, put you on a later flight if you miss your connection. If you have two tickets, then it is your responsibility to get to Mumbai on time for your flight to Bangalore and, if you miss the connection, you'll need a new ticket (unless the airline is feeling very friendly).

I say that "in theory" the airline will put you on a later flight because airlines have minimum "safe" connection times at each airport they serve, which essentially says "It's virtually impossible to make a connection in less than X minutes."  My understanding is that they won't sell a ticket that requires a faster connection so, if you have a ticket, that would indicate that the airline thinks a 30-minute connection is possible.  If the airline thinks it's possible, they will put you on a later flight if you miss the connection.

However, regardless of the type of ticket, it is extremely likely that you will miss your connection, unless the Udaipur–Mumbai flight routinely arrives early or the Mumbai–Bangalore flight routinely departs late. Even if you make your connection, it's very likely that your luggage won't.  According to FlightStats, the Udaipur–Mumbai flight is only on-time [75% of the time](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByFlight.do?airline=9W&flightNumber=2094&departureAirportCode=UDR&arrivalAirportCode=BOM) and the Mumbai–Bangalore flight has [excellent punctuality](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightRating/flightRatingByFlight.do?airlineCode=9W&flightNumber=397&departureAirportCode=BOM&arrivalAirportCode=BLR) so is unlikely to routinely leave late.

Overall advice: make sure you get off the first plane as fast as possible and be prepared to run for the gate for the second flight. Tell the flight attendants that you have a very short connection and they might be able to help you, for example by moving you to a seat at the front of the plane and finding out what gate you need to go to.  You should also ask your company if it's possible to change the ticket for one with a longer connection (it probably won't be; most tickets are non-refundable these days).